# Writing HTML with Foundation is so repetitive

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I'll admit, I'm not very experienced with writing code in general - I do it on a per-needed basis. Our company is researching different frameworks for writing code for emails. We stumbled across Zurb Foundation. I thought, great, it will make writing a lot less convoluted. Then, while going through the tutorials, I see this for making JUST A BUTTON:

```
<table align="center" class="container">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="row">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                      <center data-parsed="">
                        <table class="button float-center">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <table>
                                <tr>
                                  <td><a href="#">Centered Button</a></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </center>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*WHY..*?? Why does it seem that in coding everything has to a table within a table within a table header, within a table row, within a table cell, within a table row. It goes on forever and literally makes me angry when I look at that. I don't see why making a simple button cannot be 1 line of text, that's it.

Why does code have to be so long and convoluted for the simplest things?

Comment: Seems like overkill to have 5 nested tables just for a button - I guess the outer one is your container, the second is your layout, but 3 extra just for a button - go with a different framework!  Also, why have they put it inside a th?  Shoddy at best

Comment: pete's points are right - it should be inside a `<td>` to begin with. I recommend viewing some free HTML Email templates to see how coding email templates tends to work and go from there :)

Comment: The docs are probably not correct. Inky is used by Foundation Emails: https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/inky.html

Comment: This is not Zurb's fault, but the most bare-bones way to create a button the way people expect to see it and that involves lots of table cells. Email clients vary widely in their support of HTML and thus you're still stuck with tables for layout, mostly because of Microsoft Outlook and Google Mail: https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-design/complete-guide-to-create-your-first-email-template/

Answer (score 0):

Foundation Emails uses Inky - a custom template language (like all other email frameworks), which generates this for you.

https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/inky.html

Answer (score 0):

Emails are a different beast and if you hand write tables this is common. As Daniel pointed out, Inky is the way to avoid this mess.